# How To Build A Grid Component in Angular 2 and D3

Tags: javascript, angular

I need to create a matrix and when the user zooming out it should contains more cells (smaller of course)
the user should be able to drag the matrix to see more cells 
I understood that this abilities can be implemented in D3 but don't understand how can I implement the components I need and add them the abilities. 
does somebody has an idea? component that does all of this already? example?

Comment: please consider using any of the available grids.

Comment: @Aravind I didn't find anything that answers my requirements. I need the matrix to dragged like google map, also it should behave the same when user is zooming in\out. I need map abilities for grid